# Asking for a table

Tags: idioms

What is an idiomatic way to say when entering a restaurant

- A table for two, please?
- A table for one, please?

Answer (score 5):

Well, usually you are asked: "Ско́лько вас бу́дет?" (how many of you?)
to which you can reply: "Нас [бу́дет] дво́е/тро́е/че́тверо/пя́теро/ше́стеро/се́меро/во́семь/де́вять/де́сять" etc. or "я [бу́ду] оди́н".

If nobody is asking you but you still want to indicate it somehow, then go with "Найдётся/есть ли/мне ну́жен сто́лик для/на одного́/двои́х/трои́х/четверы́х/пятеры́х/шестеры́х/семеры́х/восьмеры́х?" etc. or "на двух/трёх/четверы́х/пять/шесть/семь/во́семь/де́вять челове́к". The last option is easier to remember and scales better for large(r) numbers.

Comment: From my experience `Столик на двоих/троих/четверых, пожалуйста` is also very common

Comment: @DmitryPavlushin true, the first part of the phrase can be dropped completely and scot-free )

Comment: Note to non-native speakers: a table in a restaurant is столик, even if it is large :).